# Unable to properly configure SSL on a wordpress hosted on Heroku

Tags: wordpress, ssl, heroku, dns

I would like to force SSL on every page of a wordpress site hosted on Heroku using a custom subdomain.

Here is what I tried so far:

1. I created my wordpress project from this repository: https://github.com/mhoofman/wordpress-heroku
2. I added a custom subdomain in the Heroku settings with the following configuration:

> Configuration: mysubdomain.mydomain.com
>   DNS Target: my-app.herokuapp.com

3. I added the Heroku SSL plugin
4. I uploaded my SLL certs of my wildcard SSL certificate bought from DNSSimple to Heroku and I get back the following url: an-app-id.herokussl.com
5. I created a CNAME redirection from mysubdomain.mydomain.com to an-app-id.herokussl.com
6. The wordpress is configured as bellow in `Settings -> General`:

> WordPress Address (URL): http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com
>   Site Address (URL): http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com

7. The HTTPS plugin is configured as bellow:

> SSL Host: mysubdomain.mydomain.com PORT: default port
>   Force SSL Administration: Checked
>   Force SSL Exclusively: Checked
>   Remove Unsecure Elements: Uncheked
>   Debug Mode: Checked
>   Proxy: No

Without any further custom configurations.

**I have one problem:**

1/ When I go to this URL: https://mysubdomain.mydomain.com I'm redirected to http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com

What did I miss?

Comment: I am not familiar that much with Wordpress, but shouldn't `WordPress Address` and `Site Address` be with `https://`

Comment: No, otherwise I have a redirection loop :/

Comment: Then it looks like there is something wrong in your `.htaccess` file, can you show it?

Comment: I don't have any .htaccess file at the root of my project.